# Регулярка работает некорректно

Tags: python, python-3.x, регулярные-выражения, строки, re

Допустим есть такой код:

```
import re

is_lock_ness_monster = lambda string : True if re.search(r'\btree fiddy\b' or r'\b3.50\b' or r'\bthree fifty\b', string) else False



print ("Fixed Tests")

def fixed_tests():

    print ('Basic Test Cases')

    def basic_test_cases():
        print (is_lock_ness_monster ("Your girlscout cookies are ready to ship. Your total comes to tree fiddy"), "---", True)
        print (is_lock_ness_monster ("Howdy Pardner. Name's Pete Lexington. I reckon you're the kinda stiff who carries about tree fiddy?"), "---", True)
        print (is_lock_ness_monster ("I'm from Scottland. I moved here to be with my family sir. Please, $3.50 would go a long way to help me find them"), "---", True)
        print (is_lock_ness_monster ("Yo, I heard you were on the lookout for Nessie. Let me know if you need assistance."), "---", False)
        print (is_lock_ness_monster ("I will absolutely, positively, never give that darn Lock Ness Monster any of my three dollars and fifty cents"), "---", False)
        print (is_lock_ness_monster ("Did I ever tell you about my run with that paleolithic beast? He tried all sorts of ways to get at my three dolla and fitty cent? I told him 'this is MY 4 dolla!'. He just wouldn't listen."), "---", False)
        print (is_lock_ness_monster ("Hello, I come from the year 3150 to bring you good news!"), "---", False)
        print (is_lock_ness_monster ("By 'tree fiddy' I mean 'three fifty'"), "---",  True)
        print (is_lock_ness_monster ("I will be at the office by 3:50 or maybe a bit earlier, but definitely not before 3, to discuss with 50 clients"), "---", False)
        print (is_lock_ness_monster (""), "---", False)

    basic_test_cases ()

fixed_tests ()
```

*Интересно почему в 3 случае выводит неверный ответ, хотя еcли поставить только **3.50** как первый аргумент, то все идеально работает ?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Логическое ИЛИ вернёт первый непустой элемент, т.е. `r'\btree fiddy\b' or r'\b3.50\b' or r'\bthree fifty\b'` вернёт `\btree fiddy\b`.

Используйте следующий код:

```py
is_lock_ness_monster = lambda string : True if re.search(r'\b(?:tree fiddy|3\.50|three fifty)\b', string) else False
```

См. [пример работы кода](https://ideone.com/0Piweg).

Вместо

```
re.search(r'\btree fiddy\b' or r'\b3.50\b' or r'\bthree fifty\b', string)
```

нужно

```
re.search(r'\b(?:tree fiddy|3\.50|three fifty)\b', string)
```

где `|` означает "ИЛИ" *в регулярном выражении*.

Comment: А что вы сделали с точкой в 3.50 ? Она тоже, что-то значит внутри регулярного выражения ?

Comment: Неэкранированная точка найдёт любой символ кроме первода строки.

Comment: А **?:** что значит ?

Comment: @Diareich Ну почитайте уже какой-нибудь мануал по регулярным выражениям, вы про каждый символ будете отдельно спрашивать? :)